# GridDB - Define When and Where Data is physically stored in Memory

Tags: griddb

What is the criteria for when GridDB automatically flushes stale data to disk? The Intro mentions prioritization as CPU->Cache->Memory->Disk. I am also curious the level of data that is being flushed at once (rows within a container vs. partitions or the containers themselves)